# In Linux, how can I completely disregard the contents of /etc/ld.so.cache?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

For the purposes of prototyping a new set of shared libraries in a development sandbox (to which I don't have root access), I'd like to know how to execute a binary while completely overriding the contents of `/etc/ld.so.cache`, so that *none* of the system libraries get loaded.

How can this be done? I have looked at mechanisms like setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable or launching the program wrapped inside `/lib/ld-linux.so`, but these methods all seem to *supplement* the loading of libraries from `/etc/ld.so.cache`, but not *override* it completely.

Help?

Answer (score 2):

Short of providing your own loader, there is no way to ignore the library path cache.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a good way to do this directly on your host system, but you could use a chroot or a container (Docker/LXC/etc) to isolate your application and ignore the host's ld.so.cache simply by not mounting it into the chroot/container.